# How can I return the specified type in generic method?

Tags: c#

I want to get specified type value from database. Here is my code:

```
public static T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            Databases.Context Context = new Databases.Context();
            var i = Context.Setting.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Key == key)?.Value;
            if (i == null) {
                return default;
            }
            switch (typeof(T))
            {
                case Type intType when intType == typeof(int):
                    {
                        if (int.TryParse(i, out int Result))
                        {
                            return Result;
                        }
                        else{
                            return default;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

As the code above, part of my code is about to return int type value. However, VS reports an error that it cannot convert int to T. How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: You are supposed to return `T` but return an `int` instead (`Result` is of type `int`), how do you think it should work?

Comment: Variable names should begin in lowercase, so they don't get confused with property and class names, which begins in uppercase.

Comment: @Progman Even I convert it like (T)Result, it cannot work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this, you need to convert to the respective type.

```
public static T Get<T>(string key)
{
    
    Databases.Context Context = new Databases.Context();
    var i = Context.Setting.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Key == key)?.Value;
    if (i == null)
    {
        return default;
    }
    switch (typeof(T))
    {
        case Type intType when intType == typeof(int):
            {
                if (int.TryParse(i, out int Result))
                {
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Result, typeof(T));
                }
                else
                {
                    return default;
                }
            }
    }

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(default, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: This may look cool, but 1) you have to handle individual types separately (int.TryParse, bool.TryParse) anyway so the switch will get big and ugly :) b) The users of this method could assume that `Get<uint>` would work, but it won't.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide different versions of your function for different types:  `GetAsInt`, `GetAsString`, etc.

A common pattern is to have the shared code in a helper method which returns a string and then  specialised methods call `TryParse`.

Something like:

```
int? GetAsInt(string name) 
{
   var s = GetSetting(name);
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return null;

  if(int.TryParse(s out var i)) return i;

 return null; //or throw

// repeat for uint, long, etc. as needed
```

You could also provide `Try` versions
: `bool TryGet(string name, out int setting)`